# Убрать незаполненные столбцы DataGrid Wpf MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm, datagrid

Есть класс содержащий в себе много полей.

```cs
public class AppealModel
{
    public string CaseNumber { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string CourtRegion { get; set; }
    public string CourtNumber { get; set; }
    public bool FileExist { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; } = false;
    public string EnforcementProceedingsNumber { get; set; }
    public string EnforcementProceedingsId { get; set; }
    public string Osp { get; set; }
    public string CopyrightHolderName { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string CourtName { get; set; }
}
```

Коллекция с этим объектом подключена к `DataGrid` `ItemSource`:

ViewModel:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<AppealModel> _dataTable;
public ObservableCollection<AppealModel> DataTable
{
    get => _dataTable;
    set => Set(ref _dataTable, value);
}
```

XAML:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable}"
```

так же, в ручную, были подключены `Data.Grid.Columns`:

```xml
<DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Номер дела" Binding="{Binding CaseNumber}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Короткое имя" Binding="{Binding ShortName}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Файл обращения" Binding="{Binding File}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Текст обращения" Binding="{Binding Text}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Регион суда" Binding="{Binding CourtRegion}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="№ Исп. пр." Binding="{Binding EnforcementProceedingsNumber}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="id Исп. пр." Binding="{Binding EnforcementProceedingsId}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="ОСП" Binding="{Binding Osp}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Правообладатель" Binding="{Binding CopyrightHolderName}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Клиент" Binding="{Binding ClientName}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Суд" Binding="{Binding CourtName}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Далее идет простое наполнение коллекции, но не во все столбцы! т.к. сама таблица решает разные задачи и не все данные нужны для той или иной.

Пример загруженных данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно избавиться от пустых столбцов.

Как это сделать?

Comment: проблема тривиальная, а в интернете никто с подобным не сталкивался. вообще никто. я походу первый.......

Comment: сделайте им Width=0, но вы хотите странного. Зачем иметь колонки, которые не надо заполнять?

Comment: @aepot не помогло. странное решение с вашей стороны, вся таблица стала мега корявой

Comment: @aepot колонки НАДО заполнять! и заполняются они в зависимости от необходимой задачи!

Comment: Мне же не стоит создавать под миллион задач миллион DataGrid таблиц и моделей под них?

Comment: Visibility настроить?

Comment: Ответ был удалён, потому что вы никак на него не отреагировали.

Comment: @aepot, вы серьезно предлагаете мне, для решения данной задачи использовать рефлексию?

Comment: У вас куча других вариантов? Никто не настаивает.

Comment: @aepot, конвертор?

Comment: @aepot, можешь ответить на вопросы под твоим ответом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение в лоб. Прятать колонку, если там null во всех строках.

Заведите конвертер, получится немного рефлексии

```
public class TableColumnVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is not IEnumerable || parameter is not string propertyName || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        Type type = null;
        PropertyInfo pi = null;
        foreach (object item in (IEnumerable)value)
        {
            if (type is null)
            {
                type = item.GetType();
                if (type.IsValueType)
                    return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            if (pi is null)
                pi = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
            if (pi.GetValue(item) is not null)
                return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

В данном случае ячейка будет считаться пустой, если там `null`.

После добавления конвертера в проект нужно пересобрать проект, и только потом переходить к редактированию XAML

Подключаю конвертер

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <TableColumnVisibilityConverter x:Key="TableColumnVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

И для колонок задать Visibility

```xml
<DataGridTextColumn
    Header="Суд"
    Binding="{Binding CourtName}"
    Visibility="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Converter={StaticResource TableColumnVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=CourtName}"/>
```

Должно работать. Если нужно динамическое обновление видимости колонок, типа если внезапно внести через код данные в какую-то колонку, то она сразу должна отобразиться, то придется усложнять и параллельно вязаться к какому-то свойству, которое должно триггерить обновление состояния колонок через `MultiBinding` и соответственно `IMultiValueConverter`.

---

Данное решение доработано: [Binding.Converter к Visible DataGridTextColumn](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1512606/373567)

Comment: благодарю. До конвертеров только сейчас дошел. Извиняюсь за излишнюю дерзость, если обидел ;3

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER не за что, успехов

Comment: не работает решение, может я что то упустил?

Comment: и как это сделать динамически, не совсем понимаю

Comment: я не могу даже дебагером туда добраться, програ просто не вызывает конвертор даже.. что делать?

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER если конвертер не вызывается, значит не в нём проблема, верно? Тогда зачем вы оштрафовали меня отменив принятие ответа? Почему решили не задавать отдельный вопрос? Почему не дали мне никакой информации, чтобы я смог хоть как-то вам помочь?

Comment: я не знал, что штрафую вас. Ваше решение не работает, я убрал галочку. Все сделал так как вы указали. Конвертор просто на просто не вызывается. Вы пробовали провести тоже самое у себя?

Comment: Я решил не задавать отдельный вопрос, дабы избежать возмущений по этому поводу, так как вопрос касается этой темы напрямую.

Comment: единственное что могу сказать, так это то что столбцы лежат в DataGrid.Columns
<DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Номер дела" Binding="{Binding Path=CaseNumber}"
                                                Visibility="{Binding Path=ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=CaseNumber}"/>

Comment: xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:appSend.Controllers.Converter" - подключенное расположение конверторов
<converter:TableColumnVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter"/> - сам конвертор в Page.Resources

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER а вы пробовали сначала заполнить, коллекцию, и только потом присвоить ее в свойство `DataTable`? Либо вызвать `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.DataTable));` для этого свойства, чтобы спровоцировать привязки на обновление? Я кажется знаю, в чем дело, в том что скойство, к которому идет привязка данных не обновляется, следовательно и конвертер не вызывается.

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER данный вопрос относится к проблеме невызова конвертера, а не проблеме скрытия столбцов в таблице, его можно было задать отдельно.

Comment: задам отдельный развернутый вопрос

Comment: @yava43DEVELOPER кстати название для свойства `DataTable` не очень удачное, потому что есть такой класс в .NET, так же называется. Это путает.

Comment: да понимаю. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1512606/binding-converter-%d0%ba-visible-datagridtextcolumn