# Binding.Converter к Visible DataGridTextColumn

Tags: c#, wpf

Необходимо прибиндить конвертор к DataGridTextColumn.

DataGrid.ItemsSource прикреплен к:

```
private ObservableCollection<AppealModel> _dataTable;
public ObservableCollection<AppealModel> DataTable
{
     get => _dataTable;
     set => Set(ref _dataTable, value);
}
```

(в прикрепленно ViewModel соответственно)

XAML:

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:appSend.Controllers.Converter"

<Page.Resources>
        <converter:TableColumnVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Номер дела" Binding="{Binding Path=CaseNumber}"
                                                    Visibility="{Binding Path=ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=CaseNumber}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Короткое имя" Binding="{Binding Path=ShortName}"
                                                    Visibility="{Binding Path=ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=ShortName}"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
```

описал без ненужных подробностей, все подключено как положено, ошибок нет, проект компилируется.

Converter:

```
public class TableColumnVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is not IEnumerable || parameter is not string propertyName || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
                return Visibility.Hidden;
            Type type = null;
            PropertyInfo pi = null;
            foreach (object item in (IEnumerable)value)
            {
                if (type is null)
                {
                    type = item.GetType();
                    if (type.IsValueType)
                        return Visibility.Visible;
                }
                if (pi is null)
                    pi = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
                if (pi.GetValue(item) is not null)
                    return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            return Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: повторюсь, дебагер даже не доходит до конвертора

Comment: Пробовали переприсвоить в свойство `DataTable` коллекцию с готовыми данными, то есть сначала заполнить, а потом в свойство положить? Либо после заполнения вызывать `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.DataTable))`

Comment: Кстати, возможно я тогда перепутал и вместо `Visibility.Hidden` надо `Visibility.Collapsed` использовать. Поправил в прошлом ответе.

Comment: я использую ObservableCollection<> для DataTable, он и так вызывает OnPropertyChanged насколько мне известно..

Comment: речь идет не о том, что происходит внутри ObservableCollection, а снаружи, речь про свойство DataTable, я пытаюсь понять источник проблемы

Comment: я попробовал сделать DataTable = new();
 OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.DataTable)); - ничего

Comment: Пробовали переприсвоить в свойство `DataTable` коллекцию **с готовыми данными**, то есть сначала заполнить, а потом в свойство положить? Либо после заполнения вызывать `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.DataTable))`?

Comment: List<AppealModel> list = request.ToList();
                                    ObservableCollection<AppealModel> datalist = new();

                                    foreach (var item in list)
                                    {
                                        datalist.Add(item);
                                    }

                                    DataTable = datalist;
                                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.DataTable));

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145274/discussion-between-yava43developer-and-aepot).

Comment: @aepot, не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `DataGridTextColumn` не является частью визуального дерева и привязки на ней в принципе не работают. Единственное, что с этими привязками работает - это ресурсы `StaticResource`.

Через конвертер мне победить не удалось. Но если задача сводится к управлению видимостью колонок, то можно сделать это через вьюмодель для них.

Использую код из [прошлого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1506806/373567) и делаю вот такую вьюмодель

```
public class AppealColumnViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool caseNumber = true;
    private bool shortName = true;
    private bool file = true;
    private bool text = true;
    private bool courtRegion = true;
    private bool courtNumber = true;
    private bool fileExist = true;
    private bool done = true;
    private bool enforcementProceedingsNumber = true;
    private bool enforcementProceedingsId = true;
    private bool osp = true;
    private bool copyrightHolderName = true;
    private bool clientName = true;
    private bool courtName = true;

    public bool CaseNumber { get => caseNumber; set => Set(ref caseNumber, value); }
    public bool ShortName { get => shortName; set => Set(ref shortName, value); }
    public bool File { get => file; set => Set(ref file, value); }
    public bool Text { get => text; set => Set(ref text, value); }
    public bool CourtRegion { get => courtRegion; set => Set(ref courtRegion, value); }
    public bool CourtNumber { get => courtNumber; set => Set(ref courtNumber, value); }
    public bool FileExist { get => fileExist; set => Set(ref fileExist, value); }
    public bool Done { get => done; set => Set(ref done, value); }
    public bool EnforcementProceedingsNumber { get => enforcementProceedingsNumber; set => Set(ref enforcementProceedingsNumber, value); }
    public bool EnforcementProceedingsId { get => enforcementProceedingsId; set => Set(ref enforcementProceedingsId, value); }
    public bool Osp { get => osp; set => Set(ref osp, value); }
    public bool CopyrightHolderName { get => copyrightHolderName; set => Set(ref copyrightHolderName, value); }
    public bool ClientName { get => clientName; set => Set(ref clientName, value); }
    public bool CourtName { get => courtName; set => Set(ref courtName, value); }
}
```

В основную вьюмодель заношу свойство

```
public AppealColumnViewModel ColumnsState { get; } = new();
```

Далее создаю класс для ресурса-прокси

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy));

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore() => new BindingProxy();

    public object Value
    {
        get => GetValue(ValueProperty);
        set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Далее вношу это в ресурсы `DataGrid`

```xml
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="ColumnsState" Value="{Binding ColumnsState}"/>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

И делаю вот такую привязку

```xml
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Номер дела" Binding="{Binding CaseNumber}"
                    Visibility="{Binding Value.CaseNumber, Source={StaticResource ColumnsState}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Теперь можно делать вкл и выкл колонки просто задав

```
ColumnsState.CaseNumber = false;
```